# Is FMS data more reliable and plentiful than OBD data?

Tags: obd-ii, can-bus

Im looking into both OBD and FMS. I have read that FMS provides more data, yet obd seems to have much more PIDs available? Is this correct or am i missing something. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean “looking into”? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Exactly what Mike said ... It really depends on what information you want. Isn't FMS for vehicle tracking data? (Doesn't FMS stand for *Fleet Management System*?)

Comment: Hi, Its research based. OBD is widely used for fleet management,  although i have read that FMS is a better option. So im curious as to how so? The OBDII pid wiki page shows 100s of available PIDs, is there more available info through FMS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

FMS and OBD are different things.

FMS (Fleet Management System) is used in telematics, you can track vehicle speed, fuel, coolant temperature, GPS location, brake, clutch, gas pedal and more with it.

OBD (On-board diagnostics) as you can guess from the name is more for diagnostics of the vehicle. OBD systems give the vehicle owner or repair technician access to the status of the various vehicle subsystems.

It really depends what you want to achieve, if your goal is telematics FMS is your thing, if it's diagnostics OBD.

Comment: Hi, yes you are correct. But OBD is widely used for fleet management too and seems to be very effective. OBD dongles to smartphone apps etc. Im curious as to how much more data is available through FMS compared to OBD

Comment: It depends on software and hardware of the vehicle. But I would say all the telemetry data that you can access via OBD, you can access it via FMS, Via FMS you can also access driving hours engine working hour and so on while it's not always possible via OBD. The telemetry data is a lot more and a lot more accurate via FMS.